# How to move divs using css media queries?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, media-queries

I have a footer on the desktop screen, what looks like this:

[image]

but on tablets (width <= 960px) I need to create something like this using media queries:

[image]

The problem is, that i dont understand how to place divs correctly without using empty div

here is my code for desktop

jsx:

```
<footer>
    <div className="footer-content">
        <div className="col">1</div>
        <div className="col">2</div>
        <div className="col">3</div>
        <div className="col">4</div>
        <div className="col">5</div>
    </div>
    <div className="another-stuff">
        another stuff
    </div>
</footer>
```

and css:

```
.footer-content {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 7%;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Tried to use

```
.footer-content{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  .footer-content .col {
    flex: 1 0 33%;
  }
```

but divs 4 and 5 was moved in the middle of the page.

Comment: On tablets, does the element 5 need to be aligned under element 3, and element 4 under element 2? Or just aligned to the right? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @MrUpsidown yes, elements should be aligned as you wrote. 5 under 3 and 4 under 2

Comment: I am no flexbox expert but I doubt you could achieve that when using `justify-content: space-between;` because the "space between" would be different when you have one line with 3 items and one with only 2...

Comment: @MrUpsidown thank you so much! That was a problem

Answer (score -1):

use css flex property which is "nowrap".

Comment: Please add details / code / examples to your answer.